# How to order a collection by two nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to order some objects through a field in the second nested association. My request model has two fields (user and owner). My owner model has a user field in there as well. A request could have a different user and owner.

The problem with this is that it orders the users on the requests table, but I want it ordering on the owner's user_id and not on requests' user_id.

```
Request.includes(owner: [:user]).order('users.name')
```

Comment: What are the relationships? Has_many through? Belongs_to? Specify the models relationships. If you want requests ordered by owners why not:  Request.includes(owner: [:user]).order('owners.name').references(:owner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you need to use:

```rb
Request
  .joins(owner: :user)
  .includes(owner: [:user])
  .order('users.name')
```

Remember that [`includes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) != [`joins`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins),